# Apps hidden at Windows Phone Store

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I recently open an account at Microsoft as a developer. I published my first app and everything was okay. My advertisments were working on the app okay. Then, I published another application and by the time my second app was in the "Store" everything of my account is hidden.

For example, none of my apps are now on Store, even If I search it with keywords, exact name and not even with my Dev name.

Another issue, is that when my second app was published none advertisment of my apps is working.

P.S. I can access my apps through a link ONLY either from PC or windows phone and only then I can download it. But, most people are just searching for an app and then install it. None has the link.

This is major issue

Comment: This isn't programming related.

Comment: I have the same issue, since November my app just disappeared in the Windows Store, but is accessible via direct link.

Comment: @simon_says today microsoft publish an article with the promise to fix it and acknowledging the problem causing to its developers let's wait a bit longer.. Is not the best but what to do.. Microsoft needs a big push if it wants better market shares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following link, your apps are mostly `hidden` in the store and you can't access them but by using the direct link..

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/10/managing-hidden-apps-beta-apps-and-visibility-of-in-app-purchases-in-dev-center/

this article will help you understand the statuses of apps in the dev center..

**UPDATE:**
Your problem will not be fixed by asking here then, contact Windows Dev Center Support.

Comment: thank you but I checked that before I post in Stackoverflow.. I found several articles about that problem that exists in the store of Microsoft since November 2015.. But really thank you for your answer

Comment: Answer updated, you'll never get the answer - contact the support

Comment: Thank you! but I was asking if there is any solution before I contact the support team of Microsoft! Thank you again